# Prepared Statement to DB setting variable type handling

Tags: java, date, prepared-statement, jodatime

This question is to do with generating a preparedstatement from a hash of strings and dealing with some strings that are Date, Times and Int.

I have a Database, the column names of this database are stored in list "columns".

I also have a hashmap "pdf" which stores fieldnames and values from a PDF document.

The code below looks for a matching column name from the DB against the pdf hashmap and if found inserts it.

```
StringJoiner col = new StringJoiner(",");
StringJoiner val = new StringJoiner(",");
//First Iteration: Create the Statement
for(String c : columns) {
//Your PDF has a matching formfield 
   if(pdf.hasKey(c)) {
   col.add(c);
   val.add("?");
   }
 }
 String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO table (%s) VALUES (%s)",     col.toString(), val.toString());
 try(PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
   //Insert position in statement
   int pos = 0;
   //Second iterations: Bind the values to the statement
   for(String c : columns) {
     //Your PDF has a matching formfield 
    if(pdf.hasKey(c)) {
       insert.setString(++pos, pdf.get(c));
   }
 }
     insert.executeUpdate();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

This works well, but I need to handle a few cases. The pdf has the following fields which are Int and Date, Time:

Age (Int)
DOB (Date)
Score (Int)
DateStart (Date)
TimeStart (Time)

I also want to modify the DB to just have a single DateTimeStart field which will hold both.

Now I did have a go at handling this with something like:

```
                if (c.toLowerCase().contains("date")) {
                System.out.println("A Date field has been found: " +c);
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern ("dd/mm/yyyy");
                DateTime startdt = formatter.parseDateTime(pdf.get(c));
                insert.setDate(++pos, startdt);
            }
            if (pdf.containsKey(c) && !c.toLowerCase().contains("date")) {
                insert.setString(++pos, pdf.get(c));
            }
```

But this doesnt work. For starters setDate doesnt accept DateTime objects, even if they only contain a date. Also trying to get my head around the new prepared statement with the database now only containing "DateTimeStart" instead of "DateStart" and "TimeStart" gave me a headache.

Any help here would be appreciated. I am already using Joda since its Java7.

Cheers

-Al

```
                if (c.toLowerCase().contains("date")) {
                    System.out.println("A Date field has been found: " +c);
                    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/mm/yyyy kk:mm");
                    long millis = formatter.parseMillis(pdf.get("DateStart") +" " +pdf.get("TimeStart"));
                    Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(millis);
                    insert.setTimestamp(++pos, timeStamp);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard JDBC accepts date/time only as instances of

```
java.sql.Date       (date only)
java.sql.Time       (date/time with 1 second resolution)
java.sql.Timestamp  (date/time with fractional second resolution)
```

You must convert your Joda objects into one of these, and use the correct method (`setDate`, `setTime` or `setTimestamp`) on `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Thanks @Jim So it would appear I need to use setTimestamp to do the insert?

Comment: I think that's what I said in my answer... you choose what precision you want, convert your timestamp to one of the `java.sql` classes and use the correct `set` method on `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Thanks @Jim so I will end up storing my DateTime in the DB (MS Access) as a milliseconds time value.

Thats pretty user unfriendly?

Still working out how to convert my date string to a milliseconds value thats accepted by JDBC.

Comment: No, it will be stored in whatever native format the database uses for date/time.  You're confusing the interface (`java.sql.Timestamp`) with the implementation at the back end.  If your DB column is a date/time it will stay that way and JDBC will ensure the conversion is correct. You really should experiment with this to see what you're going to get.  You could answer a lot of your own questions.  Experimentation is the best way to learn.

Comment: Hi @Jim. Thanks for the replies. I have done a bit of experimenting and I think I am close with the code I have added to the question (see above)

Comment: Hi @Jim. Thanks I got it to go. Cheers again.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful it is expected that you will upvote it and if it solved your problem, mark it accepted by clicking on the checkmark above left.